# Time conversion Ruby on Rails 4 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, heroku

Part of my logic for sending an email to a supplier is that the promise date must be less than today's date in order to send the email. For whatever reason, it is passing as true even though it should be false. I test it in the console and it shows false, but it sends the email... so I am guessing it is passing as true.

```
def self.send_vendor_openorder_notification(user, vendor)
    po_collection = Array.new
    user.purchase_orders.where({open_order: true, vendor_number: vendor.vendor_number}).where.not(email_last_sent: Time.now.midnight).each do |x|
      if x.promise_date == nil || DateTime.strptime(x.promise_date, '%m/%d/%y') + 7.hours < Time.now.midnight
        if x.email_sent == false
          po_collection << x.id
          x.email_sent = true
          x.email_last_sent = Time.now.midnight
          x.save
        end
      end
    end
    if po_collection.empty? == false
      VendorSender.open_order_sender(user, vendor, po_collection).deliver_later
    end
  end
```

Here if promise_date is nil or less than today at midnight, it should pass. However, a promise date of "09/19/2016" is passing as true on 09/19/2016. In heroku console(this is deployed through Heroku), this is false... What am I missing here?

```
irb(main):038:0> DateTime.strptime("09/19/16", '%m/%d/%y') + 7.hours < Time.now.midnight
=> false
irb(main):039:0> DateTime.strptime("09/19/16", '%m/%d/%y') + 7.hours
=> Mon, 19 Sep 2016 07:00:00 +0000
irb(main):040:0> Time.now.midnight
=> 2016-09-19 00:00:00 -0700
irb(main):041:0>
```

Comment: It is returning false because both dates are exactly the same and you asked if Time.now.midnight was lower than the DateTime.strptime.

Comment: @luissimo Is correct, the dates are the same, but with different time zones.

Comment: I want it to return false. The problem is that it is returning true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with your TimeZone.

Always use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`. [Click here](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/) for more details.

You can change your `if` condition like this.

```
x.promise_date == nil || (Time.zone.parse(x.promise_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))) + 7.hours < Time.zone.now.midnight
```

Hope this helps.